# Replace line return characters(\n) with a real line return in a pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, hive

I am faced with a problem on a dataframe recovered from the hive database. My dataframe contains a field with several line returns. I would like to replace the line returns ( \n) by real line returns.
my dataframe looks like this:

```
columns = ["language","definition"]
data = [("Java", "Java is a high-level\n class-based, object-oriented programming\n language that is designed to have as few implementation\n dependencies as possible"), ("Python", "Python is an interpreted\n object-oriented, high-level\ programming language")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df.show(truncate=False)
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|language|definition                                                                                                                                          |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Java    |Java is a high-level\n class-based, object-oriented programming\n language that is designed to have as few implementation\n dependencies as possible|
|Python  |Python is an interpreted\n object-oriented, high-level\n programming language                                                                        |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My output expected replaces line breaks(\n) with real line breaks like this:

```
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|language|definition                                                                                                                                          |
+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Java    |Java is a high-level
 class-based, object-oriented programming
 language that is designed to have as few implementation
 dependencies as possible|
|Python  |Python is an interpreted
 object-oriented, high-level
 programming language
```

if anyone has any idea how to thank you so much.

Comment: Where will you store the data at the end?

Comment: The data will store In csv file at the end of process.

Comment: What is the purpose of viewing the lines in new line?

Comment: The goal was to recover data on a hive table and replace the returns line character  (\n) by real break line. I found a way to do this, but hive manages this by adding a following property. set hive.fetch.task.conversion=more;  For further details, the source is: https://www.mail-archive.com/issues@hive.apache.org/msg29338.html